# Setting maxExecutorRetries on SparkSession

Tags: java, apache-spark

When several consecutive failures occurs while using SparkSession to load/write some data, eventually Spark stops working, instantly returning "Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext", regardless of the possible results.

After a research, I discovered "spark.deploy.maxExecutorRetries" on [spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html/), which states:

> If an application experiences more than spark.deploy.maxExecutorRetries 
>   failures in a row, no executors successfully start running in between those 
>   failures, and the application has no running executors then the standalone
>   cluster manager will remove the application and mark it as failed. To 
>   disable this automatic removal, set spark.deploy.maxExecutorRetries to -1.

So i tried this:

```
public static SparkSession getNewSparkSession() {
        return SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkJdbcSuite").master("local[*]").config("spark.deploy.maxExecutorRetries", "-1").getOrCreate();
    }
```

I expected that regardless of how many consecutive failures, it kept trying, but doesn't look like I applied correctly the parameter.

I also tried to set `-1`, `3`, `"3"`, and use a `SparkConf,set("spark.deploy.maxExecutorRetries", "-1")`, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone knows how to properly set this property?

Comment: have you tried in spkar-shell in client mode?

Comment: Our servers run in VM's, we don't actually run spark locally. I could try it out, but I'm not confident of the results

Comment: im talking abt .master("local[*]") change it to yarn and see

Comment: It didn't accept "yarn" as master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing this:

```
SparkConf config = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkContext");
SparkContext context = SparkContext.getOrCreate(config);
return SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(context).getOrCreate();
```

and adding this to the `finally` block after using spark:

```
SparkSession session = sparkSession.get();

session.sparkContext().stop();
session.close();
```

Looks like SparkSession was trying to use a stopped context, this way it always gets a new one, unless something it executing. But if the `Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext` occours, it ends up on the `stop`, and uses a new one next time.